# why drawImage is not drawing the image on jframe

Tags: java, swing

When I am trying to display the image on `JFrame`, it's not getting loaded. I have defined `displayImage(File file)` method in the class which is extending the class `JFrame` -

```
public void displayImage(File file)
{ 
        BufferedImage loadImg = StegImage.loadImage(file); 
        System.out.println(loadImg.getWidth() + "x" + loadImg.getHeight() + " image is loaded.");
        setVisible(true);
        setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
        setBounds(0, 0, loadImg.getWidth(), loadImg.getHeight()); 
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)getRootPane().getGraphics();
        System.out.println("Drawing the image.");
        g.drawImage(loadImg, null, 0, 0);  
}
```

Output I am getting on terminal is -

```
877 x 587 image is loaded.
Drawing the image.
```

But in the Frame it is not visible.

Comment: Of the code statements in that code block, only the last two avoid being 'either sub-optimal or outright wrong'.  Whatever resource you are using for learning Java, change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should not paint or call a component's graphics the way you did. If you need custom graphics rendering, use a `JComponent` or `JPanel` which has the `paintComponent` function. Override it to draw inside of it.

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent
{
  public BufferedImage bgImg; // your background image

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(bgImg, x, y, this); // draw background image
  } 
  }
}
```

Read your image and assign it to the `bgImg` upon creation of an instance of `MyCanvas`. For your use case, you want to use the image as your JFrame's background: add the instance of  `MyCanvas` as content pane to the `JFrame`.

```
 jFrame.setContentPane(new MyCanvas()); 
   // you might want to set layout or other thing to the
  // MyCanvas component before adding it
```

Read some online tutorial such as [custom graphics drawing and painting on component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: `g.drawImage(bgImg, x, y, null);` should be `g.drawImage(bgImg, x, y, this);`. But this image *might* better be displayed in a `JLabel`.

Comment: sure leave it. Any kind of positive direction, suggestion is always appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

1st 
 create a public BufferedImage loadImg; variable on top of your class and initialize it later in your displayImage(File file) function;

```
   loadImg = StegImage.loadImage(file);
```

2nd
 create a function to draw the Image;

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);  // Paint background

    // Draw image at its natural size first.
    g.drawImage(loadImag, 0, 0, this); //85x62 image

    // Now draw the image scaled.
    g.drawImage(loadImag, 90, 0, 300, 62, this);
}
```